# SBT - using two versions of library in a single project?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a project with a bunch of tests written for Scalatest 1.x, which use the `ShouldMatchers` class, which was deprecated in version 2.x. Going forward, I want to use version 2 for new tests, but this will mean I have to refactor all my existing tests (which I can do, but it'll take some time).

In the meantime, is there a way in SBT to compile existing classes against Scalatest 1.x, and new ones against Scalatest 2.0?

Or more generally, compile some classes in a project against a different version of a library to other classes? (I'm aware that this might be quite a horrible idea.)

Comment: I think this will mess up the class-path. Can't you just create two sub-projects for the two types of tests?

Comment: in the same project? you can't. only in different projects. You could have some trouble with ides like IntelliJ though

Comment: The very issue is not a IDE one, but a classpath one, aka dependency hell

Comment: @0__ Possibly, if that's the way to go. My SBT-fu is weak, so that would probably be a good exercise. Thanks for your answer below. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @cchantep You're probably right, but I'm entertaining the possibility that as a build tool that is good at sorting out dependency hell, sbt might have some way to deal with this situation. Or it might not... that's my question.

Comment: You can "shade" one version of the dependency, but in the end it's a workaround, not a transparent fix (needs to update some imports imports in the code)

Answer (score 3):

You could create two dependent sub-projects, one for each version of scala-test.

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))

lazy val oldTests = project.in(file("old-tests"))
  .dependsOn(root)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"
  )

lazy val newTests = project.in(file("new-tests"))
  .dependsOn(root)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"
  )
```