# Different versions of slick libraries in the same application

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I have a question. Suppose I have a legacy application A which uses slick 2.0

I am writing a new library B which uses slick 3.0

Now I add a reference to library B in A and try to use library B from A.

Will application A break because B brought a new version of slick along with it?

What if at the time of adding a reference (in build.sbt) I use the "excludes" like

```
"MyOrg" % "B" % "1.0.0" exclude("slick")
```

Now can both application A and library B work together?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861292/sbt-using-two-versions-of-library-in-a-single-project

Comment: I tested mysql and I found that its impossible to use slick 2 and slick 3 in the same jar.